# How to add tags to time series created by metadata template in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: path, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Msg: 508: Path [root.test.s77.xxxxx.x1] does not exist

I would like to ask a question about Apache IoTDB. Can tags be added to the time series created through the metadata template? When I tried to add a tag to one of the time series, the error information prompts that the path does not exist: Msg: 508: Path [root.test.s77.xxxxx.x1] does not exist. Anyone know how to solve this problem or can tags be added to the metadata created time series?

Really no idea. Someone help please.